# How to use multiple exceptions in the recurrence of an event in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is my problem:

Based on a spreadsheet where the entry is done of reservations for training sessions, I'm building an Apps Script to put each reservation into the calendar.
Each reservation contains a time period from start to end, resulting in a recurring event where every week there is a training session.

So far so good, mainly because of the valuable help and code examples that I found here at SO.
I'm now able to add, change and remove calendar events, based on the spreadsheet. I reached a new level in Google Apps Script programming when that happened :-)

But the one thing I keep struggling with is how to add multiple exceptions to each reservation that has them.

One of the fields in the sheet is containing  the dates that should be excluded from the reservation period, in the format: "DD-MM-YYYY, DD-MM-YYYY". I am able to convert them into an array of dates (exceptions):

```
[Sat Dec 05 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020, Sat Dec 26 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020]
```

When I want to build the recurrence part, I'm running out of steam. I am able to find examples where one exclusion is used, but I need to be able to build multiple for one event.

I have tried to use an array, but that didn't work for me.

This is what I have:

```
 for (var k=0;k < exceptions.length ;++k) {             // doorloop het hele array
     var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
                      .addWeeklyExclusion(exceptions[k])
                      .until(new Date(CEUntil));
  }
```

This is the error I'm getting:
"*Exception: The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.RecurrenceRule.addWeeklyExclusion.*"

What am I doing wrong?

I changed it to:

```html
        var recurrence = [];
          for (var k=0;k < exceptions.length ;++k) {             // doorloop het hele array
            Logger.log(exceptions[k]);
            recurrence[k] = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
                            .addDateExclusion(new Date(exceptions[k]))
            Logger.log(recurrence[k].length());
          }
          event.setRecurrence(recurrence, Tstart, Tstop);          

            recurrence[k+1] = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
                            .until(new Date(CEUntil));
          event.setRecurrence(recurrence, Tstart, Tstop);
```

This is giving another error:

*Exception: The parameters (number[],(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.CalendarEventSeries.setRecurrence.*

Comment: `addWeeklyExclusion()` does not accept arguments. I'm not sure, but you're probably better off using the `addDateExclusion(date)` method. You should create the EventRecurrence before the loop, then add your exclusions to it within the loop.

Comment: Are the recurrent events always at the same time? Why not setting the recurrence when creating each event and then updating the event deleting the days needed?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Diego. I added the change to my original post. But it gives me another error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay attention to what values you're passing into your functions. They are listed as "parameters" and clearly described in the documentation for the methods linked below.

1. [`addWeeklyExclusion()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#addweeklyexclusion) does not accept any values, but you were trying to pass it a date.
2. [`setRecurrence(recurrence, startTime, endTime)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series#setrecurrencerecurrence,-starttime,-endtime) expects an [EventRecurrence](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence) object, but you're passing it an array.

Each event series has one `recurrence` and that `recurrence` may have multiple exceptions. There is no need to create an array of recurrences.

```
function createRecurringEvent() {
  const Tstart = new Date('December 5, 2020 04:00:00 PM EST');
  const Tstop = new Date('December 5, 2020 05:00:00 PM EST');
  const CEUntil = new Date('January 10, 2021');
  
  const recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
  const rule = recurrence.addWeeklyRule().until(CEUntil);
  
  const exceptions = [ 'December 5, 2020', 'December 26, 2020' ];
  exceptions.forEach(function(exception) {
    rule.addDateExclusion(new Date(exception));
  });
  
  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries(
    'Recurring Event',
    Tstart,
    Tstop,
    recurrence
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a great deal! I will add my working code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

With the great help of Diego, I was able to get my code working.

This is the relevant snippet of the code to update an event, leaving the exceptions out of the series of events:

```js
var exceptions = record[26].split(',');
var event = calIndoorHall.getEventSeriesById(CEId);
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence();
var rule = recurrence.addWeeklyRule().until(CEUntil);
exceptions.forEach(function(exception) {
  rule.addDateExclusion(new Date(exception.toString()));
});
event.setRecurrence(recurrence, Tstart, Tstop);
```

Looking at the beautiful simplicity of this piece of code, I wish I would be more eloquent in JS/GAS. A matter of (a lot more) practice, I guess.

Thank you for your help!